# How do I create a multilevel popup prompt like in Settings-Safari-Clear History?

Tags: iphone, xcode, popup, confirmation

I have a UITableView settings screen with options important enough that I should be asking the user to confirm whether or not they meant to hit them.  I want to follow the apple convention as much as possible, thus I'd like to implement a warning that looks like this:

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v283/DurAlvar/Screenshot2010-02-03at13314PM.png

Anyone know how to do this?

Edit:

Thanks KennyTM for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with AppStore Settings bundles.

(Creating a custom action sheet is restricted to internal "preference bundles".)

(Why there are so many questions to mimic the internal preferences recently...)